# Python check if 2 strings represent the same path if the path has spaces

Tags: python, filepath

consider the following path, which can be expressed by either one of the following methods :

```
y="/Library/Application\ Support/Logic/Sampler\ Instruments/01\ Acoustic\ Pianos/Steinway\ Grand\ Piano\ 2.exs"

x="/Library/Application Support/Logic/Sampler Instruments/01 Acoustic Pianos/Steinway Grand Piano 2.exs"
```

I'd like to find a matching method that ignore the `\` before the space.

I've tried `os.path.expanduser` but it didn't give me equal strings, but merely added additional slash to the path that was written in the `\` notation.

```
os.path.expanduser(y)
'/Library/Application\\ Support/Logic/Sampler\\ Instruments/01\\ Acoustic\\ Pianos/Steinway\\ Grand\\ Piano\\ 2.exs'

os.path.expanduser(x)
'/Library/Application Support/Logic/Sampler Instruments/01 Acoustic Pianos/Steinway Grand Piano 2.exs'
```

How can I return True on these 2 equal representations, or return the same string so that i can match it later ? Thanks !

Comment: Try `x.replace("\\", "") == y.replace("\\", "")`.

Comment: `.replace()` [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

Comment: thought of it, but I was looking for a more robust solution because theoretically path can contain slashes

Comment: Could `os.path.samefile(x, y)` be a way to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'd like to find a matching method that ignore the \ before the space.*

You might simply `.replace` `\`  using   as follows

```
y="/Library/Application\ Support/Logic/Sampler\ Instruments/01\ Acoustic\ Pianos/Steinway\ Grand\ Piano\ 2.exs"
x="/Library/Application Support/Logic/Sampler Instruments/01 Acoustic Pianos/Steinway Grand Piano 2.exs"
print(y.replace(r"\ "," ")==x.replace(r"\ "," "))
```

output

```
True
```

Explanation: I used so called raw-string to avoid need to escape `\`. `\` which are not followed by space will be left without alteration.